# start an application included in the same solution

Tags: c#, .net, windows, execution

I have a little C# project and I want to start an application with endings(bad english) like executable.exe -o 99. But I want the "executable.exe" being within my C# project. So I copied the target executable into the project workspace.
The compiled executable now should contain the whole other executable in its memory.
The main application now uses the other application as utility while runtime.
This may have installer program like characteristics, but the utility app is just used temporary.
To build the structure for achieving this functionality would take enough effort.

So my question is: How to provide already compiled and runnable utility application inside of another main application?

Somehow like an assert.

Comment: Please don't put things like "C#:" in your subject. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @Noli: is your problem that you don't know how to start your application passing command-line arguments?

Comment: @Dan I want to find a way having a already compiled file in my project to let the code use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the executable also includes a project with compiled libraries you can add it as a reference in your project and use its public classes.

If not you may want to do something like:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

...

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\path\to\application\executable.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = "-o 99";
Proccess.Start(startInfo);
```

Not sure if this is what you need but its the only thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Mhm no thats not it, I want to have it it my C# project, and just let the code start it, maybe it can be extracted to an place temporary but it should be 1 executable file, my HDD broke after 3 days... and the source code is deleted. The app was coded in vc++ 2008 so i cant import is as reference.

Comment: @Noli If there is no access to the source code and you didn't use Managed C++ code then adding as a reference is indeed not an option. If the code was in MC++ or C++/CLI then adding a reference may still be an option if the original application was coded with inter-language operations in mind.